# Is Bootstrap.connect Thread safe?

Tags: netty

I need to issue several connections from diferent threads. I would like to know if I Bootstrap.connect is thread safe or I have to do some syncronization.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's thread-safe and so can be used by multiple threads.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10189315)

Comment: I'm not sure why this not answers the question... he asked if its thread-safe and I said yes it is....